# Make changes to referenced datatable in Parallel.ForEach loop

Tags: c#, datatable, ref, parallel.foreach

I'm trying to create a method which when passed a datatable reference with pingable host names, tries to ping each of the hosts and then change the value of corresponding column and row depending on ping success.

However i cannot use references in Parallel.ForEach method. Is there any way i could make this work?

Here's my code:

```
public void checkON(ref DataTable PCS)
    {

        Parallel.ForEach(PCS.AsEnumerable(), pc =>
            {
                string loopIp = pc["Name"].ToString();
                if (PingIP(loopIp))
                {
                    DataRow[] currentpc = PCS.Select("Name = '{0}'", loopIp);
                    currentpc[0]["Online"] = "ON";
                }
                else
                {
                    DataRow[] currentpc = PCS.Select("Name = '{0}'", loopIp);
                    currentpc[0]["Online"] = "OFF";
                }
            }
        );}
```

Comment: Well why do you need `ref`? From your code I can't see a reason. Moreover is `DataTable` thread-safe? (it should, IMO but...are we sure?)

Comment: @Adriano I am pretty sure it *is not* ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless code **explicitly says** that it is thread-safe, you should assume it is not - and therefore access must be synchronized. The `ref` in your code serves no purpose. Each `pc` is a `DataRow`, so you can access that directly:

```
string loopIp;
lock(someLockObject) {
    loopIp = (string)pc["Name"];
}
string online = PingIP(loopIp) ? "ON" : "OFF";
lock(someLockObject) {
    pc["Online"] = online;
}
```

where `someLockObject` is shared between *all* of the callers, because you can't make assumptions about the threading model:

```
object someLockObject = new object();
Parallel.ForEach(PCS.AsEnumerable(), pc =>
        { ... });
```

In particular, you can't just lock the row because *`DataTable` doesn't store data in rows* (it stores it in columns; no, really).

Comment: Yeah, this works right. Reall thank you for help. Got stuck in here for quite some time. Beginner :D But i have questions if you might :) Why when trying to .Select from datatable in the parallel loop it does not find the corresponding rows. Another question would be what's be the best way to implement this function so it doesnt lock up UI thread and the changes to the datatable would be visible in real time. This datatable serves as datasource for DataGridView control.

Comment: @dazgen `DataTable` publishes change notification; as such it is a **really bad idea** to have it actively connected while you are making changes from other threads... But to not freeze, same rules as always: don't block the UI thread - and note that since `Parallel.ForEach` is a synchronous call (it blocks until all complete), blocking the UI thread is exactly what you are doing.